# interpolateCornersCharuco does not find any corners, ids

Tags: python, opencv, aruco

I found this code somewhere, but it isn't working for me. In my example picture it detects and draws the markers, but interpolateCornersCharuco dosen't work.

```
ARUCO_DICT = cv2.aruco.DICT_4X4_50
SQUARES_VERTICALLY = 8
SQUARES_HORIZONTALLY = 11
SQUARE_LENGTH = 0.01
MARKER_LENGTH = 0.007
# ...
PATH_TO_YOUR_IMAGES = 'path'
# ------------------------------
def calibrate_and_save_parameters():
    # Define the aruco dictionary and charuco board
    dictionary = cv2.aruco.getPredefinedDictionary(ARUCO_DICT)
    board = cv2.aruco.CharucoBoard((SQUARES_VERTICALLY, SQUARES_HORIZONTALLY), SQUARE_LENGTH, MARKER_LENGTH, dictionary)
    params = cv2.aruco.DetectorParameters()

    # Load PNG images from folder
    image_files = [os.path.join(PATH_TO_YOUR_IMAGES, f) for f in os.listdir(PATH_TO_YOUR_IMAGES) if f.endswith(".png")]
    image_files.sort()  # Ensure files are in order

    all_charuco_corners = []
    all_charuco_ids = []

    for image_file in image_files:
        image = cv2.imread(image_file)
        image_copy = image.copy()
        marker_corners, marker_ids, _ = cv2.aruco.detectMarkers(image, dictionary, parameters=params)
        marker_corners = tuple(marker_corners,)
        cv2.aruco.drawDetectedMarkers(image_copy,marker_corners,marker_ids)
        # If at least one marker is detected
       
        if len(marker_ids) > 0:
            cv2.aruco.drawDetectedMarkers(image_copy, marker_corners, marker_ids)
            charuco_retval, charuco_corners, charuco_ids = cv2.aruco.interpolateCornersCharuco(marker_corners, marker_ids, image, board)
            if charuco_retval:
                all_charuco_corners.append(charuco_corners)
                all_charuco_ids.append(charuco_ids)

    # Calibrate camera
    retval, camera_matrix, dist_coeffs, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.aruco.calibrateCameraCharuco(all_charuco_corners, all_charuco_ids, board, image.shape[:2], None, None)

    # Save calibration data
    np.save('camera_matrix.npy', camera_matrix)
    np.save('dist_coeffs.npy', dist_coeffs)

    # Iterate through displaying all the images
    for image_file in image_files:
        image = cv2.imread(image_file)
        undistorted_image = cv2.undistort(image, camera_matrix, dist_coeffs)
        cv2.imshow('Undistorted Image', undistorted_image)
        cv2.waitKey(0)

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

calibrate_and_save_parameters()
```

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lPSS.jpg)

I've tried other pictures but, I always have the same problem

Comment: No, i ended up using the plain chess pattern

Answer (score 0):

According to a github issue in opencv-contrib, this is because of a charuco pattern change in aruco module.

The given example image is of "legacy" mode in opencv aruco module since some version. As a result, if you want to use this pattern, which has aruco marker in the first square of the board, you should do this after board deffinition:
'''
board.setLegacyPattern(True)
'''

Now you should be able to detect charuco corners without problem.